# Flask AttributeError on import: module 'typing' has no attribute 'NoReturn'

Tags: python, flask, python-typing

```
import flask
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\vigne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "C:\Users\vigne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple
  File "C:\Users\vigne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InternalServerError
  File "C:\Users\vigne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 884, in <module>
    class Aborter:
  File "C:\Users\vigne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 906, in Aborter
    ) -> t.NoReturn:
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'NoReturn'
```

I am getting this error whenever I try importing Flask.

Currently, I am on Python version **3.6.0**.

Comment: i dont know what was actually causing this but i found out that using an intreputer alike 3.6.2 or above just works fine but if your using a lower intrepreter its gonna give that error on just running the pip command too

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and it has to do with the version of Python==3.6.0 that you are using. As suggested by Alveona, upgrading it to 3.6.2 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

They [fixed this issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4040) in a new release (Flask 2.0.1).

Try updating flask with `pip install Flask --upgrade`. Alternatively, upgrade your Python version to 3.6.2.

Comment: Or, you can update your Python to version 3.6.2 if there is any issue with upgrading flask itself

Comment: Actually, i am working on a project and all my packages are configured for this version so  i will try doing flask upgrade!

Comment: Also if possible could u fetch me the link to flask 2.0.1 because currently mine gets upgraded to 2.0.0 and the issue persists @Alveona

Comment: @Kratos_bawa ah, it's currently unreleased  

so yeah, the only valid way then is updating your python version to >=3.6.2

Comment: oh okay i would try updating then!