# FLASK Server breaks with an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR on passing context to template

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, internal-server-error

I am unable to figure out the issue with my Flask Server which doesn't get up as soon as I try to pass any context or global variable from my view function to the template. The browser only shows 'Internal Server Error' on trying to access the url. After a little observation, I realized that the problem was only occurring on trying to access the passed context variable in my template. The server gets up when I remove the jinja syntax from my template.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", name="Satya")
```

home.html

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hi {{name}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the stacktrace that I get on running the app using 'flask run':

```
**I just can't seem to get past this and it is so frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.**
AttributeError
AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'test'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\FlaskProject\main.py", line 7, in home
return render_template("home.html", name="Satya")
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 997, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, globals)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 137, in load
code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 749, in compile
source = self._parse(source, name, filename)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 606, in _parse
return Parser(self, source, name, filename).parse()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 1038, in parse
result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 1012, in subparse
add_data(self.parse_tuple(with_condexpr=True))
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 725, in parse_tuple
args.append(parse())
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 523, in parse_expression
return self.parse_condexpr()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 528, in parse_condexpr
expr1 = self.parse_or()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 543, in parse_or
left = self.parse_and()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 552, in parse_and
left = self.parse_not()
File "D:\MCA\BIT-2020\VirtualEnvs\test_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 560, in parse_not
if self.stream.current.test("name:not"):
AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'test'
```

Comment: Probably the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67659135/flask-token-object-has-no-attribute-test-render-template-error

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish I had found this fix earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use app.run() method to start your app.
Add this to your code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", name="xyz")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True) # You can set debug to false as weel, though it will help you debug your code
```

Now just run app.py, it should work

Comment: I suggested a different method because I couldn't replicate the error, the same code you provided works perfectly on my machine both ways (flask run and app.run()), so you might want to try a different method. If this doesn't work either, can you please tell me your jinja version? My version is Jinja2==3.0.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mayank, but I've already tried running it with app.run() and it throws the same error. Even I've never faced this issue before with Flask. IF THE CODE IS WORKING FINE ON YOUR MACHINE, I suspect it has something to do with the latest versions of Flask or Jinja2 or some other component. I'm using Flask==2.0.1 and Jinja2==3.0.1; I'll try downgrading my Jinja2 version to 3.0.0 and check.

Comment: Downgrading Jinja2 to version 3.0.0 worked like a charm. Thank you once again for the suggestion. I had been breaking my head over this for the last two days.

Comment: It's alright, glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

[FIXED] Just for anyone visiting this thread in the near future. This problem is with the latest version of Jinja2==3.0.1 at the time. So, adhering to the following version specifications will make the app run smooth:

**Python > 3.6.0**
**Jinja2 < 3.0.1**

The version of flask doesn't really seem to be making a difference here.